# Change scroll velocity based on scroll position

Tags: flutter

I want to limit the user to a certain scroll speed at a certain position, say if the offset is less than x, no matter how hard you scroll, the scroll animation won't go faster than y.

How is that doable as I couldn't find any sources that explain this? I've tried overriding scrollPhysics and Simulator but without success.